# Updating Conda Environment's Dependencies Along WITH Python Version

Tags: python-3.x, conda

I am going to be updating the major version of Python on my Conda environment. I have many other dependencies like torch and numpy that will likely get removed when the python version updates.

So I know:

`conda install python=3.8`

will update the python version. And from what I recall dependencies will be lost if they don't work in that python version. How can I get conda to commensurately update all the dependencies *with* the Python version so I don't lose them?

Not really much to try here other than the command above, which removes any dependencies that can't work with the new Python version.

Comment: Have you tried a dry run? E.g., `conda install -d python=3.8`? What does it suggest it will do? Typically, Conda will not uninstall anything you have previously explicitly requested to be installed.

Comment: @merv Thanks for the reply! Yeah, so from doing this it seems like conda does either get rid of packages or downgrade them if you change the python version. But if you change the version of certain packages, it only gives a message if there are any conflicts.